# Как сделать раскрывающееся меню?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

есть меню с подменю, как при клике на пункт меню, вывести его подменю, сейчас раксрываются все подменю

```
<ul :class="$style.catalogCategories">
  <li v-for="(category, index) in categories" :key="index" :class="$style.categoryItem">
    <div :class="$style.catalogCategoryHeader" @click.prevent="isOpen = !isOpenSubCategory">
      <nuxt-link to="" :class="$style.catalogCategoriesLink">
        {{ category.name }}
      </nuxt-link>
      <span :class="$style.cataloCategoryItemToggleSub">+</span>
    </div>
    <ul v-if="category.sub" :class="[$style.catalogSub, isOpenSubCategory ? $style.catalogSubOpen : '']">
      <nuxt-link v-for="(sub, index) in category.sub" :key="index" to="" :class="$style.catalogSubLink">
        {{ sub.name }}
      </nuxt-link>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```